# Does the QUIC protocol sends ClientHello in clear text?

Tags: security, ssl, man-in-the-middle, quic

In general, the first time I heard it, I was very happy that Clienthello Tls messages will be fully encrypted inside the QUIC protocol, since this is a big leap forward in privacy.
That there is no need for ESNI, but yesterday I saw this [article](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GV2j-PGl7YGFqmWbYvzu7-UNVIpFdbprtmN9tt6USG8/preview)(Title: Parsing QUIC Client Hellos) on the Chronium project, it is written about parsing ClientHellos, or I misunderstood something, or they mean decrypting ClientHellos already on the server side and not by a person in the middle.
There's a [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-esni-09) reference about encrypting standart, but I as far as I understand it still depends on DNS.
Can you correct me? Thanks.

Comment: *"...  I was very happy that Clienthello Tls messages will be fully encrypted inside the QUIC protocol ..."* - I'm not sure what you've heard or read, but it was wrong or you've interpreted it wrongly. Apart from that - such questions are more on-topic at [security.se].

Answer (score 3):

`ClientHello` messages are encrypted in QUIC, but the keys are published in the [QUIC specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-quic-tls-33#section-5.2) and so the Initial packets are easily decrypted.

Comment: That's a different question! I may answer it if you accept my answer to the original.

Comment: If you'll answer all of questions then :). Btw it's done. I read about new extension to TLS 1.3 Encrypted Client Hello which should fix this issue. https://blog.cloudflare.com/encrypted-client-hello/ Yes what's the point if QUIC keys can be decrypted?

Comment: Yow? Any news on that?